# Can a world completely free of violence sustain life and civilization for a long time?

Tags: society

I have heard the (fictional) story of the demise of a civilization with no concept of violence after they were invaded by alien and inability to resist.
But in the absence of external influence, would this civilization evolve or die for some other reason?

Comment: You may need to provide more details. Explain more about the civilization you are asking about, what do you mean by "no concept of violence"?

Comment: Hi, while it is up to you to decide when to accept an answer as a general etiquette is advised to wait at least 24 hours before doing so. This allows people around the world to join in before the answer is accepted. Plus you are going to receive more and possibly even better answers.

Comment: @JANXOL 
I think that means "don't know how to cause violence" and "don't need to know how to protest"

Comment: @DuncanDrake Thank you. I will pay more attention to this. I thought this answer was enough to satisfy my request, but it seems the comments indicate too much I missed out. Can people still contribute answers after I have accepted an answer or can only comment?

Comment: VTC: Needs Details. Please provide a very specific definition of "violence." I know of no evolutionary evidence that is non-competitive, which is the essence of "violence." Insofar as I know, "violence" is much more broadly defined by the victims of action and choice than it ever will be by the perpetrators of action and choice. So without a clear definition, this isn't an easily answerable question.

Comment: You can very easily undo the green check mark!

Comment: @Mido yes, people can still post answers after one has been accepted put have less incentive to do so. Sometimes the OP does not even come back to check them anymore. As elemtilas points out you can also undo your choice.

Comment: Does "*no concept of violence*" mean that they are unfamiliar with all conflict? Or that they are familiar with it, but use another name for it, or bundle it with another concept (like 'karma' or 'self-defense')? Or that they are in denial that they are capable of (perhaps regularly commit) violent acts? Or does it mean something else?

Comment: '...or die for some other reason?' is much. much too broad. VTC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"violence" is a rather broad term. What is violence?

Is beating your neighbor to take his apples violence? I guess so.

Is beating the wolf who is trying to eat your kid violence? I guess so, though justified.

Is killing a boar to have a meal violence? Well, for the boar yes.

Is harvesting a plant to have dinner violence? Well, I guess the plant would prefer to keep living.

> But in the absence of external influence, [...]

If your "civilization" cannot exert any violence, it will likely quickly starve. Sitting below a tree waiting for a fig to drop in your mouth cannot feed that many people (and it would still be seen as violence since it deprives other living things of their food)

Comment: "*If your "civilization" cannot exert any violence, it will likely quickly starve.*" not necessarily. There are all sorts of factors that can mitigate that. For example, the civilisation can be *fed*. Farm animals like chickens and pigs tend to live despite not exerting violence. The civilisation might also be able to eat in alternative fashion. Artificially created nutrients might just need mundane lab work. Or they might be able to get power from the Sun. Or they could form symbiotic relationship with some species. Overall, I don't think the statement holds as an absolute.

Comment: I wonder if being a parasite could be seen as 'violent' provided the host does not feel pain or has not his health significantly compromised. Eating fruits and then planting the seeds could be seen as a kind of parasitic life after all.

Answer (score 2):

Freedom from violence is not freedom from disagreement or conflict.

One could imagine a scenario where societal disagreement (religious,  political, philosophical, etc.) grew to a point of schism where one side simply decides to dissociate from the other entirely.  This side could withhold mineral resources or manufactured products within their territory from the other and the other could retaliate.  In a delicate and heavily interlinked commercial and manufacturing environment like the one we have in the real world, this could cause a societal collapse.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer - yes!

Whilst any life-form on Earth that was completely pacifistic would have a hard time surviving, let alone thriving and forming a civilisation under the threat of our predators, an alien civilisation on an alien planet could have their biology designed such that the capacity to digest the meat from the planet's animals is extremely difficult or impossible to evolve. Since all animals on the planet would then be herbivores, you can quite likely imagine a species having no need to engage in violence as there would be no threats that they would need to fight.

Comment: You are assuming that eating a plant is no violence at all. I guess a plant would disagree, else why would some grow thorns?

Comment: ... true. I assume you could class a society that doesn't attack animals as non-violent for the context of this question, since a species that won't harm plants is going to starve and is therefore not applicable to OP's question.

Comment: This answer is basically, "just because humans are violent doesn't mean aliens need to be..." which relies on facts not in evidence. Every aspect of evolution is competitive and we've seen no example of a non-competitive evolutionary process. The idea that, just because we haven't seen an example doesn't mean it can't exist, is fanciful and opinion-based, which isn't the answer model Stack Exchange prefers. Do you have any evidence at all of any kind of evolution that wasn't competitive?